# Using components from multiple environments (windows , & linux) in sync

Tags: linux, windows, vmware, csh

I was supplied two components by different parties; one that works on windows 32 bit and another that works in linux 64 bit. For my program I need to take the output files of the windows component and put them as an input to the linux component.

I have installed vmware player on windows to run a virtual 64 bit ubuntu machine. And when transferring the files manually everything works, How can I automate this process?

I thought of automatically producing a dummy file "flag.txt" in the shared folder and writing a script in the ubuntu machine that check if it exists every 5 seconds and if so runs the linux component. Is that a feasible solution? If so, any idea which command in csh do i use?

Answer (score 0):

An emulator independent way to trigger commands and download files from Linux machines is OpenSSH. There's an SSH client available for Windows using MINGW.
Use `ssh` to run commands remotely on the Linux machine and `scp` to transfer files. Both programs can be invoked from the command-line and batch scripts.

If you want to stick to VMware features, you could use shared folders to synchronize the files. Share a writeable folder on your Windows host and mount it in the Linux guest. Both can see and access the same files inside the shared folder.

**References:**

- [Install windows version of ssh client – openssh (a putty alternative)](http://www.tomatosoft.biz/blog/2011/10/23/install-windows-version-of-ssh-client-openssh-a-putty-alternative/)
- [Viewing a Shared Folder](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_sharedfolder_viewing.html)
- [where is the shared folder in linux inside Vmware Player?](https://superuser.com/questions/423880/where-is-the-shared-folder-in-linux-inside-vmware-player)